# Multipe array in meta_input

Tags: array, wp-insert-post, meta-value

I want to insert post with wp_insert_post and add meta_input in it.

I have to send my data with array but I have problem to send more than one

Here is my code :

```
          wp_insert_post( array(
          'post_title'    => $post['title'],
          'post_type'     => 'werknemers',
          'meta_input'    => array(
            foreach($movies as $movie) {
              $i++;
              array(
                  'key'   => 'title' . $i,
                  'value' => $movie['title']
              ),
              array(
                  'key'   => 'qty' . $i,
                  'value' => $movie['qty']
              ),
              array(
                  'key'   => 'desc' . $i,
                  'value' => $movie['desc']
              )
            }
          )
      ) );
```

---

I change it to this but now it doesn't send values of array to database correctly

```
          foreach($movies as $movie) {
        $i++;
        $post_args = array(
          array(
              'key'   => 'title' . $i,
              'value' => $movie['title']
          ),
          array(
              'key'   => 'qty' . $i,
              'value' => $movie['qty']
          ),
          array(
              'key'   => 'desc' . $i,
              'value' => $movie['desc']
          )
        );
      }



      wp_insert_post( array(
          'post_title'    => '1',
          'post_type'     => 'departure',
          'meta_input'    => $post_args
      ) );
```

Comment: you can't put a for loop inside an array like that, you need to do the loop before that and assign it to a variable. Arrays and other values can only contain values. This doesn't look like a WordPress problem but a PHP programming problem. I'd suggest going over variables/arrays/loops on php.net

Comment: @TomJNowell I put them outside of array and add to an variable but still have problem

Comment: In your 2nd code snippet, you're redefining `$post_args` for every `$movie` in `$movies`. Set `$post_args = array();` *before* the `foreach()` begins, and then you can add items to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd code snippet, you're redefining `$post_args` for each `$movie`. Try this instead:

```
$post_args = array();
foreach($movies as $movie) {
    $i++;
    $post_args[] = array(
      array(
          'key'   => 'title' . $i,
          'value' => $movie['title']
      ),
      array(
          'key'   => 'qty' . $i,
          'value' => $movie['qty']
      ),
      array(
          'key'   => 'desc' . $i,
          'value' => $movie['desc']
      )
    );
  }

  wp_insert_post( array(
      'post_title'    => '1',
      'post_type'     => 'departure',
      'meta_input'    => $post_args
  ) );
```

Comment: I try this code but still doesn't insert any value in post meta